# What should I do to pick the right consultant to open offshore bank account

Tags: banking, international

http://www.ifsc.gov.bz/licensed-service-providers/list-a/

have lists of approved consultant in Belize

- Is the list credible?
- Is there a site that collect testimonies for these?
- How do I know which one is best or good?

I do not know which bank I should bank on. Some banks have low transfer fee. Some banks have low minimum balance, etc.  This guy seems to know his stuff.  Moreover, I am going to work on thousands of dollars. So $250 fee for good info is reasonable.

Comment: Interesting question. What are some other tags you could add?  I normally add them for you, but I am not sure.  [off-shore-accounts]? [online-banking]?

Answer (score 3):

It is unusual to need a consultant to open a bank account for you, and I would also be concerned that perhaps the consultant could take the money and do nothing, or continue to demand various sums of money for "expenses" like permits, licenses, identity check, etc.  until you give up.

Some of the more accepted ways to open a bank account are:

**A: Call up an established bank and follow their instructions to open a personal account** . Make sure you are calling on a real bank, one that has been around a while. Hints: has permanent locations, in the local phone book, and has shares traded on a national stock exchange.  Call the bank directly, don't use a number given to you by a 3rd party consultant, as it may be a trick... Discuss on the phone and find out if you can open an account by mail or if you need to visit in person.

**B: Create a company or branch office in the foreign country, assuming this is for business or investing.**   and open an account by appointing someone (like a lawyer or accountant or similar professional) in the foreign country to represent the company to open an account in person.

If you are a US citizen, you will want to ask your CPA/accountant/tax lawyer about the TD F 90-22.1 Foreign Account Bank Report form, and the FATCA Foreign Account Tax Compliance Act. There can be very large fines for not making the required reports.

The requirements to open a bank account have become more strict in many countries, so don't be surprised if they will not open an account for a foreigner with no local address, if that is your situation.

Comment: I do not know which bank I should bank on. Some banks have low transfer fee. Some banks have low minimum balance, etc. This guy seems to know his stuff.

Comment: @JimThio - we can't help you select a bank, only you can decide on the criteria that suits your needs.  Are you concerned about the trustworthiness of the banks?

Comment: I understand that Belize and Costa Rica are nice places, but personally I would be hesitant to open a bank account in central or south America without visiting in person and having some sort of reason like business in the area.